# Azure Custom Script Extension CLI / Powershell for Local files

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, dsc

I am trying to run a Script using Custom Script extension on the VM.
I am able to upload my Custom Script ( on my local drive) navigating via UI in the Extension settings but I am not able to do the same via CLI / Powershell

I am looking for 
az vm extension (CLI) / Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension command that can help me to do the above i.e. to

Upload / Run a custom script extension for a script present @ local disk or Azure Repo

I have tried various ways the closest I could get is 
Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension -FileUri "file:///D:/scripts/TINFAD01.ps1" -ResourceGroupName p1cad-draas-sb-dev-dev -Location eastus -VMname TINFAD01 -Verbose -Name TINFAD01DSC -Run 'TINFAD01.ps1' | Update-AzVM -Verbose

Gives an error of : Part of the path not found ( I have double checked the path and it does exist)

Comment: COuld you please tell me what is "upload a Custom script to Azure"? Is that you upload your script to Azure storage?

Comment: Please check my updated description, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

According to my test, if you want to run a Script which is on the local file system using Custom Script extension,  we need to upload the script to Azure storage. Then we can run the script. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows).
For example:
1. Upload script to Azure storage.

2. Run the script

```
Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName nrg-win -VMName n-win01 -Location eastus -FileUri "https://nlistorageaccntv1.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/myScript.ps1" -Run 'myScript.ps1' -Name DemoScriptExtension
```

[image]

Besides, if you just want to run the local script and do not want to upload it to Azure Storage, you can use Azure VM Run Command feature. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command)

For example:

```
Connect-AzAccount
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName '<myResourceGroup>' -Name '<myVMName>' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath '<pathToScript>' -Parameter @{"arg1" = "var1";"arg2" = "var2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

NEW ANSWER based on edited/modified question:

Did you had a look here, it is possible to store your PS script in BlobStorage and reference it as the script location for the ExtensionScript CLI command:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#script-location
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#extension-schema

And here you find an example on how to execute the CLI command:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#using-multiple-scripts

---

OLD OBSOLETE ANSWER

I guess you want to copy the script to a Windows VM.

One possible solution install a sftp or ssh server on the Windows VM and use sftp or scp.

Another solution would be to leverage Azure Files and attach the network drive to the VM and your local machine and then copy the script there centraly.

You could also leverage azcopy (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files) and first copy the scripts to a blob storage and on the VM in Azure you copy them back to local.

Maybe the best approach would be to leverage Azure DevOps (free tier available) and create a Pipeline in which you are using a file copy task to put your scripts on the target VM (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops).

Comment: I am trying to run a Script using Custom Script extension on the VM.
I am able to upload my Custom Script ( on my local drive) navigating via UI in the Extension settings but I am not able to do the same via CLI / Powershell

I am looking for 
az vm extension (CLI) / Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension command that can help me to do the above i.e. to 

Upload / Run a custom script extension for a script present @ local disk or Azure Repo

Comment: Please do check my updated description for more details

Comment: please have a look at my revised answer

Comment: I want to be able to load it via my local disk because its totally possible via the GUI and would like that feature